# Jquery Common function to hide elements by attribute

Tags: jquery

I have many checkboxes and related textboxes in the page. The textboxes are hidden by default and show only if its related checkbox is checked. How should I write a common function for this, instead of a function for every checkbox.

http://jsfiddle.net/6SCMc/

something..like..:

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").click( function() {
    var x = $(this).attr("name");
$("[id=x]").toggle(this.checked);
});
```

The 'name' of the checkbox will be the id of its textbox.

Comment: Not really. The checkboxes will all be at one place and then the textboxes will follow below them. Say..in 2 fieldsets one below the other

Comment: Thank you everyone. That was super quick. I tried RajaPrabhu's answer and it worked. Single line...simple...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont need a `attribute selector` in this context, since you are targeting an id, just use the Id selector like below,

Try,

```
$("#" + $(this).attr("name")).toggle(this.checked);
```

Full code,

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").change( function() {
   $("#" + $(this).attr("name")).toggle(this.checked);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to:

1) Include jQuery in your fiddle

2) Use `change()` event instead of `click()`

3) Concatenate your `x` variable properly using `+`

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").change( function() {
    var x = $(this).attr("name");
    $("#" + x).toggle(this.checked);
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6SCMc/3/)**

Answer (score 2):

Include jQuery in your fiddle and also :

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").click( function() {
    var x = $(this).attr("name");
    $("[id="+x+"]").toggle(this.checked);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your textboxes immediately follow the checkboxes, you can do something like:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function() {
    $(this).next().css('display', this.checked ? 'block': 'none');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If your question is, how do you accomplish this show/hide functionality without binding a function call to each checkbox? Then solution is, to bind a function to a div that wraps the table, or to the table itself. Then when onClick on the div fires, traverse down the child dom elements and if a checkbox is checked, show or hide the text as necessary. So something like the following:

```
$("wrapper_div_id").click(function() {
   var checkboxes = $(this).find(":checkbox")
   for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
      // insert code here to show/hide. Sorry, I got lazy to finish writing the rest of this
      // but you get the idea.
   }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

check this one

http://jsfiddle.net/6SCMc/4/

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function(){
                if( $(this).is(":checked") ){

                    $(this).next().show()
                }else{

                }
});
```

Comment: the textboxes dont hide again when the checkbox is unchecked

Comment: If you OK this code i can add script for unchecked statement @Ruby